# PHP's _GET decodes %26para as ¶ and not &para

Tags: php, facebook

I am having an issue with `$_GET['url']` auto-decoding my encoded URI.

The URL was encoded using JavaScript's `encodeURIComponent()`. The URI that I am encoding has the following parameters: `?param4=fni-ofe-ble&param2=ofe-ble&param1=flyleaf-fb`

JavaScript encodes this portion as.`%3Fparam4%3Dfni-ofe-ble%26param2%3Dofe-ble%26param1%3Dflyleaf-fb`

When PHP's `$_GET['url']` is ran, it returns the following: '?param4=fni-ofe-ble¶m2=ofe-ble¶m1=flyleaf-fb'

How do I fix this? It seems to be encoding %26para as ¶ and not as &para.

Thanks

Comment: How do you check that it is not `&para`? did you only echo it and checked it in the normal browser window or in the source view  or did you check it in a log file?

Comment: Fixed it myself by adding to the header `Content-Type: x-www-form-encoded;` and it works fine now. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> You can do by this way.

```
$url = $_GET['url'];
$str = urlencode($url);
```

> output:

```
param4%3Dfni-ofe-ble%26param2%3Dofe-ble%26param1%3Dflyleaf-fb
```